# Best way to handle expression resulting in attribute error : 'NoneType' during loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In looping through a beautiful soup object sometimes a tag exists in one iteration but not the next. As I am also extracting the text with a chain of .text afterwards, I am running into AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' being raised.

I'm assigning all of these results to a dictionary and would prefer the values to be 'None' in the dictionary when the element does not exist. Is it better to not call .text on anything and somehow parse the HTML that is stored in the dictionary again later?

```
for review in reviews:

entry = {
    'bnm' : review.find('p', {'class' : 'bnm-txt'}).text
    'artist' : review.find('ul', {'class' : 'artist-links artist-list single-album-tombstone__artist-links'}),
    'title' : review.find('h1', {'class' : 'single-album-tombstone__review-title'}).text,
    'score' : review.find('span', {'class' : 'score'}).text,
    'label' : review.find('li', {'class' : 'labels-list__item'}).text,
    'year' : review.find('span', {'class' : 'single-album-tombstone__meta-year'}).text[3:],
    'author' : review.find('a', {'class' : 'authors-detail__display-name'}).text,
    'author_title' : review.find('span', {'class' : 'authors-detail__title'}),
    'genre' : review.find('a', {'class' : 'genre-list__link'}).text,
    'review_timestamp' : review.find('time', {'class' : 'pub-date'}).text,
    'review_abstract' : review.find('div', {'class' : 'review-detail__abstract'}).text,
    'review_text' : review.find('div', {'class' : 'clearfix flex-md'}).text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns `None` if there's no element matching the criteria. Then, when you try to call `.text` on the result, it fails with the error you've seen.

One idea could be to wrap this with a function that handles that case:

```py
def safeFindText(elem, name, attrs):
    temp = elem.find(name, attrs)
    if temp:
        return temp.text
    return None
```

And then use it in the loop:

```py
for review in reviews:
    entry = {
        'bnm' : safeFindText(review, 'p', {'class' : 'bnm-txt'})
        'artist' : safeFindText(review, 'ul', {'class' : 'artist-links artist-list single-album-tombstone__artist-links'}),
        # etc...
```

Comment: This is more neatly done using `getattr`.